# google chart vertical axis and tooltip value formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a google-chart which displays the pressure values of my room. Chart has several problems in it

[image]

- Vertical axis repeats its values, say i need vertical values at 95535 95537 95539. but all i get is 95K 95K 95K as axis values
- Tooltip when we hover over the line has the same effect
- When i add the code to make my points bigger (pointSize) that even doesn't have any effect

However charts line acts as if it is correct, by that i meant it has some ups and downs.

## I added NumberFormat formatters but what ever I do the chart doesn't change.

How do you format the vAxis and tooltips correctly?

here is the code i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('datetime', 'Timestamp');
        data.addColumn('number', 'pressure');

        data.addRows([
            [new Date('2015-11-19 18:26:05'),95245],[new Date('2015-11-19 18:19:07'),95186],[new Date('2015-11-19 18:19:06'),95186],[new Date('2015-11-19 18:12:05'),95152],[new Date('2015-11-19 18:05:53'),95151],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:58:04'),95172],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:51:04'),95152],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:44:04'),95141],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:37:04'),95111],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:30:04'),95102],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:26:04'),95112],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:19:05'),95064],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:12:04'),95042],[new Date('2015-11-19 17:05:04'),95027],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:58:04'),95032],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:51:04'),95045],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:44:05'),95042],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:37:05'),95016],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:30:05'),94990],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:26:04'),94995],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:19:04'),94985],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:12:04'),94969],[new Date('2015-11-19 16:05:04'),94955],[new Date('2015-11-19 15:58:04'),94949],[new Date('2015-11-19 14:50:18'),94987]            ]);

        var options = {
                        chart: {
                          title: 'abasingama_a1',
                          subtitle: 'Unit - Pa',
                          pointSize: 30
                        },
                        width: 800,
                        height: 300,
                        vAxis: { minValue: 95450, maxValue: 95550 },
                        pointSize: 30,
                      };
        
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern:'0.0e00'});
        formatter.format(data, 1);

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your options with `google.charts.Line.convertOptions` in the drawing of your chart.

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

should be

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

And then it'll work like you expect it.
I would try with `vAxis: { minValue: 95450, maxValue: 95550, format:'decimal'}` to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: this solves the 1st two problems, but still no points in the line for me, But that's not an actual requirement, i need to know thats all :)

Comment: You said you tried to add it earlier. If you add the points again, they will show up if you use the `google.charts.Line.convertOptions`

Comment: My bad. It should do, but won't. See this bug/feature request report: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1922

Comment: that's okay then, I have this working great!! thanks mate!