# Can't get Google Charts Axis to format in decimal

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to set an option for a specific graph in the decimal form. I went through many questions, but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working for me.

```
var temp_chart_options = {
   title: 'Temperature',
   hAxis: {title: 'Date',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#262626'}, format:'decimal' },
   vAxis: {minValue: 0, format: 'decimal'},
   keepInBounds: true,
};

temp_chart.draw(temp_data, temp_chart_options);
```

I tried doing `format: 'decimal'`, or `format: { pattern: 'decimal' }` and even did `temp_chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(temp_chart_options));` and even looked at these questions:

- [google chart vertical axis and tooltip value formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804826/google-chart-vertical-axis-and-tooltip-value-formatting)
- [Google Chart Vertical Axis and Tooltip Value Formatting](https://cmsdk.com/jquery/google-chart-vertical-axis-and-tooltip-value-formatting.html)
- [How to format numbers in Google API Linechart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204678/how-to-format-numbers-in-google-api-linechart)

But none of them seem to work :(

> EDIT

Does anyone know how to change the format of the hover?
[image: change the format of the hover]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format parameter on your vertical axis needs to specify a proper format pattern.  For example, `vaxis: {format:'0.00'}` will give you a number with two decimal places after it.

Note that [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats) is very incomplete about this.  They give an example using the presets, and an example of using separators (e.g. `'#,###'`), but there is no example showing decimal places, nor is there any complete documentation on number format specifiers that I could find.  Perhaps it is documented elsewhere, but the page I linked to above ought to at least provide a link to it if so.  It does not.  I discovered the `0.00` format by experimentation.

Comment: What you did work, but I realised that I wasn't trying to change the axis value, it was the hover value. Nonetheless, your answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the accepted answer, I needed to do a currency in GBP with 1000's separators and 2 decimal places.

The given Google 'currency' was unsuitable as it renders the currency symbol in your local currency.

I came up with this:

```
format: '£#,###.##'
```

Which could theoretically be used with any currency symbol.

This was the result:

[image: Screenshot of google charts]